# Restrict MPD clients

Tags: mpd

Is there a way to restict MPD clients to limited actions such as only adding songs to the playlist?

Background: I want to use MPD as a "jukebox" for a party, but guests should be prevented from clearing the playlist, skipping songs, etc. Clients would be Android/iOS apps.

Comment: just found out about this project: https://code.google.com/p/bazinga-jukebox/
It isn't quite what I wished for, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPD can restrict specific actions to clients identified via a password (and allows multiple passwords with different sets of allowed actions as well):

```
   password <password@permissions>
          This specifies a password for access to mpd.  The format is "password@permissions" where permissions is a comma delimited  list  composed  of
          "read",  "add", "control", and/or "admin".  "read" allows for reading of the database, displaying the current playlist, and current status of
          mpd.  "add" allows for adding songs and loading playlists.  "control" allows for all other player and playlist manipulations.  "admin" allows
          the db to be updated and for the client to kill mpd.  An example value is "somePassword@read,add".  Multiple password parameters may be spec‐
          ified.
```

(from mpd.conf(5)), so adding

```
password "<your_guest_password>@read,add"
password "<your_admin_password>@read,add,control,admin"
```

to your config file would allow you to

- connect to MPD using the password  and only be able to add songs, read the database and playlist
- connect to MPD using the password  and do everything else MPD and its clients offer